Props not Passing Props
I have just started using React and I have this ItemMenu that suppose pass props to the Sidebar but it is not working.
I have console.log it and the props from the ItemMenu seems to be working just fine

Menus.jsx

import Sidebar from './Sidebar';

export const ItemMenu = (props) => {
    console.log(props);                         // This works just fine
    return <Sidebar oneItem={props} />;         // This one is not
};

export const HiddenMenu = ({ props }) => {
    
    const IconKeys = [<Globe absoluteStrokeWidth />, <Telescope absoluteStrokeWidth />, <PencilLine absoluteStrokeWidth />];

    return (
        <div className='w-screen bg-slate-100 h-48 flex md:hidden flex-col items-center justify-center font-bold text-lg'>
            {
                props.items.map( (i) => {

                    return (
                        <div className='py-2 flex w-3/5 justify-end items-center gap-2' key={i.id}>
                            {IconKeys[i.id]}
                            <button title={i.title} onClick={ () => ItemMenu(i.title) } > {i.title} </button>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}


Sidebar.jsx

const Sidebar = ({ oneItem }) => {
  { console.log(oneItem) }           // I have this to console.log but it returns undefined
  return (
    <div className='row-span-2'>
      Side
      
    </div>
  );
};

export default Sidebar;

And everytime I clicked on the Button on the HiddenMenu  it doesnt return anything. only the Console.log() from the ItemMenu. the Props isnt passing into the Sidebar.
Help and Thank you
I have tried on removing the console.log and keep working on the OneItem  but it just gives undefined.
I want to get the data from that props so that I can work on the JSON file i have set-up on the Sidebar.


onClick={ () => ItemMenu(i.title) }

You cannot render components this way. The only way to cause a render is to set state. React will then call your component, and your component can use the new state to calculate what elements you want to be on the page.
For example:
export const HiddenMenu = ({ props }) => {
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(null);

  // ...
  return (
    <>
      {selectedItem && <ItemMenu oneItem={selectedItem} />}
      <div className="...">
        {/*...*/}
        <button title={i.title} onClick={() => setSelectedItem(i)}>
          {i.title}
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};


so then how can I pass this state/data to another component, If i am not exporting it and returning it.

so then how can I pass this state/data to another component Where is that component, relative to this one? If it's a child component, then you pass it as a prop. If it's a sibling or a parent, then you move the state up the component tree, and pass it down to each component that needs it. https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components
